# i want to ad a checkbox value in url in search page and search new query from get checkbox value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
<div class="city-list">
                    <ul>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="All" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=All'" <?php if($_GET['Bhk'] == 'All') { echo "checked='checked'"; } ?>/>All </li>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="1 BHK" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=1 BHK'"/>1 BHK </li>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="2 BHK" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=2 BHK'"/>2 BHK </li>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="3 BHK" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=3 BHK'"/>3 BHK   </li>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="4 BHK" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=4 BHK'"/>4 BHK   </li>
                        <li><input name="Bhk" type="checkbox" value="5 BHK" onClick="self.location=location.href+'?Bhk=5 BHK'"/>5 BHK  </li>




                    </ul>
                </div>
```

and my url is this : http://www.successghar.com/search-result.php?ResidentalType=Sell&ResidentialProperties=Apartment&Bhk=&budget_from=&budget_to=&City=Ahmedabad+West&ResidentalPropertySubmit=GO

i will want to when i check any check box this value auto ad on Bhk=1 Bhk,2 Bhk   place so is possible and refine new query

Comment: This is a wish, not a question... Please ask a question and show that you have put -any- effort in investigating or trying yourself.

Comment: Are you saying you want to filter results based on check boxes clicked, as you press these check boxes? Or do you click a number of boxes, then hit submit, and get a search result? The approaches are very different.

Comment: this is my question and i will want to like this http://www.makaan.com/ahmedabad-property/residential-property-for-sale-in-ahmedabad-east/search-properties?SERP=List refine search bar

Comment: yeah want to filter results based on check boxes clicked not on submit

Comment: hello floris can you help me